Warning: SPDX license identifier not provided in source file. what can I do guys?
Warning: SPDX license identifier not provided in source file. Before publishing, consider adding a comment containing "SPDX-License-Identifier: " to each source file. Use "SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED" for non-open-source code. Please see https://spdx.org for more information.
--> @uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router01.sol
I Tried using // SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
while importing:
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";

I found the fix here:
https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/issues/3623
Change to SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
